# Replace this string using wildcard?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having trouble replacing

`&start=10`

within the string

`http://url.com?rt=22&start=10&pp=fasd986asd`

I want to be able to remove the 10 value and put something else in there.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Have you tried `string.Replace`?

Comment: Cant get string.replace to work cause the value of 10 is changing each time

Comment: a regex ? where &start = xxx and then replace the xx part

Comment: Im not sure how to write that regex, can you show?

Comment: `string.Replace` on a *copy* of the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var parts = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("http://url.com?rt=22&start=10&pp=fasd986asd");
parts["start"] = "20";
var newUrl = String.Join("&", parts.Cast<string>().Select(x => x + "=" + parts[x]));
```

Answer (score 2):

yes you can use

```
HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex.Replace("http://url.com?rt=22&start=10&pp=fasd986asd", "&start=\d+", "&start=20");
```

Would be one way, or you could use `&start=(\d+)` with `Regex.Matches()` and use the match collection to find start and end index of the digit. Read the [Regex class docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6f7hht7k) to find out more.